# Need to change options of fonts for wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fonts, tinymce

i need to change the default drop down list options of the tinymce editor in wordpress to include 11pt

the default values are 8,10,12,14 i need to put 11 in this list , and to be effective for sure.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your file use like this

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme_advanced_font_sizes : "10px,12px,14px,16px,24px"
});

So you can change the font size options by this way in your running file.

Comment: please where is that file?